# Cant get DOM reference in svelte in function used in template

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm new to Svelte and a bit confused about the rendering in Svelte.
So I have this code:

```
<script>
 export let recipients: string[];
 let recipientsContainer: HTMLDivElement;
 const shouldRenderRecipient = (recipient) => {
  return !recipientsContainer?.textContent;
 }
</script>

<div>
 <div bind:this={recipientsContainer}>
  {#each recipients as recipient}
   {shouldRenderRecipient(recipient) ? recipient : ''}
  {/each}
 </div>
</div>
```

So what I expected would happen was that the view would be rendered and then the recipients would be looped and for each recipient, it'd check `renderRecipient`, and depending on whether there was already a rendered recipient it would either throw true or false. But what confused me is that the `shouldRenderRecipient` function is entered before we have a valid DOM reference for `recipientsContainer`.

I thought we would have access to `recipientsContainer` inside of `shouldRenderRecipient` function since `shouldRenderRecipient` function only gets called once the view is rendered?

Comment: The reference is not directly available but when the component is mounted inside the `onMount` callback https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-this

Comment: Sorry coming from angular, and i thought that the function only runs when the component is mounted. Because Im not calling `shouldRenderRecipient` function anywhere else except inside of the div.

Comment: Your function is running while rendering the component thus the reference to the component is not available, It will be available once it has been mounted. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/bind-this